# How to manage application.config file to minimize code in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration, slick-2.0

For example:
I have written database config in application.config as follows:

```
    storedb{
     url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/storedb"
     slick.driver = scala.slick.deiver.MySQLDriver
     user = "user"
     pass = "pass"
    }
```

I have multiple database config and want to manage it like this:

```
    dbUrl= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"
    dbUser= "user"
    dbPass= "pass"
    slickDriver = scala.slick.deiver.MySQLDriver
    storedb{
     url = dbUrl+"storedb"
     slick.driver = slickDriver
     user = dbUser
     pass = dbPass
    }
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIR, you can do something like

```
dbUrl= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"    
dbUser= "user"
dbPass= "pass"
slickDriver = scala.slick.deiver.MySQLDriver

storedb {
 url = "${dbUrl}storedb"
 slick.driver = ${slickDriver}
 user = ${dbUser}
 pass = ${dbPass}
}
```

See some concatenation example https://github.com/lightbend/config#concatenation

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured that concatenation works like this:
url = ${dbUrl}"storedb"